# If an enum is declared in a function, what is the scope?

Tags: c

Is the enum private to the function?

```
void doSomething()
{
   enum cmds {
      A, B, C
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is "private" to the function.

Comment: @jens I disagree with the dupe target.  The question is, is A scoped to the function or can it be used outside the function.  The duplicate does not answer that.

Comment: @NathanOliver There is one answer there which answers this (but I agree that marking that question duplicate is misleading): http://stackoverflow.com/a/8448260/6600109

Answer (score 5):

The `enum cmds` type and the enumeration members `A`, `B`, and `C`, are local to the function scope.

Note that while enumerations don't introduce a new scope for their member constants, they do get scoped within the *containing* scope, in this case the function body.

```
int doSomething(void)
{
    enum cmds {
        A, B, C  // 0, 1, 2
    };

    return C;  // returns 2
}

int anotherThing(void)
{
    enum cmds {
        C, D, E  // 0, 1, 2
    };
    return C;  // returns 0
}
```

[Run the example code here on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e3551674d42c23)

Answer (score 2):

Like almost any other declaration, an `enum` type defined inside a block is local to that block.

In your case:

```
void doSomething()
{
   enum cmds {
      A, B, C
   }
}
```

the block happens to be the outermost block of the function, but it doesn't have to be:

```
void doSomething(void) {
    if (condition) {
        enum cmds {A, B, C};
        // The type and constants are visible here ...
    }
    // ... but not here.
}
```

(Goto labels are the only entity in C that actually has function scope.)

Answer (score 1):

> enums don't introduce new scope.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447946/enumeration-scope).

Comment: This answer is misleading, see the answer by Colin D Bennett.

Comment: @MarkusLaire I don't see how this answer is misleading. Colin's answer also says that it doesn't introduce a new scope.

Comment: @JordanMelo Because question is not about whether enum introduces new scope or not.

Comment: @MarkusLaire Yes I haven't explained it in detail as Colin D Bernnett and assumed it conveyed the meaning. But definitely not misleading.

Comment: @MarkusLaire I see what you mean. The answer is definitely incomplete and vague as to how it answers the question. I wouldn't say misleading. It partially answers the question in the title, but not the question in the body.

Comment: @JordanMelo No, this doesn't answer question in title even partially. That question refers to scope in which enum is enclosed in. This answer talks about whether enums create scope to their elements. These are completely different questions with different answers: While enums do not create new scope, they can be created in new scopes.

Comment: @MarkusLaire When Enums do not create new scope, doesn't it mean that they are bound to the function enclosed in? Also, it was never asked if they can be created in new scope. Question was: what is the scope and is it private to function. So I really don't see how you consider it as misleading but thanks for your comments.

Comment: @PseudoAj Question was specifically about whether enums can be enclosed in other scopes than global scope, which your answer doesn't answer to.

Answer (score 0):

As you refered in this question, The `enum cmd` you defined can **only be used in this function**. But if you define an enum in header, that you can use the all items of enum in any c file which including this header.

It is the same as the normal variable, but sometimes, The item can be used as `marco`(actually it's just an integer). That's very convenient in some cases.