# Is an enumeration constant allowed to appear in more than 1 type definition in C?

Tags: c, enums

Can two different enums in C contain the same constant value?

ex:

```
enum trafficLight{red, yellow, green};
enum americanFlag{red, white, blue};
```

is this legal?

Comment: no as there are no enumeration scopes in C. You have to use prefixes.

Comment: Even though the two definitions for `red` have the same value in this example, I believe it is still considered a name conflict, and hence illegal.

Comment: For completeness, I entered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55581434/298225) explaining how the rules in the C standard preclude the same identifier from being used in two enumerations, regardless of the value(s) given them.

Comment: Enumeration types do not have their own dedicated namespaces - enumeration constants share the same namespace as ordinary identifiers and typedef names, so they are effectively "global".  So no, you cannot use the same enumeration constant in multiple `enum` types.

Comment: So the reason that you can use the same enumeration constant in a language like java is because java treats enumerations as classes?

Comment: @user9791370 Well, kind of.